# Migrating your App Engine app from Go 1.9 to Go 1.11

Tags: go

I have update my golang version from 1.9 to 1.11. After updating sendgrid mail send not working.

I have followed below link:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences

and found that we need to Use request.Context() or your preferred context instead of using appengine.NewContext .
But when I am trying request.Context() getting request is not defined.

So how to change **appengine.NewContext to request.Context() for go111**

Here is my code:

```
func SendTestmail(c echo.Context) error {
type output struct {
    Message string      `json:"message"`
    Status  bool        `json:"status"`
}
result := output{}
//mail code
to := "myemail@mail.com"
firstName := c.FormValue("first_name")
subject := "Send Test mail"
msg := "Dear User , " + "\n \n" +
    "You have successfully Tested." + "\n " +
    "Sincerely, " + "\n \n" +
    "Team"
var Body = general.FrameEmailObj(os.Getenv("SENDGRID_SENDER"), subject, to, msg)
url := os.Getenv("SENDGRID_URL")

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(Body))
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+os.Getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
ctx := appengine.NewContext(c.Request())
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
//end mail code
result.Message = "send mail success."
return c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, result)
}
```

I am getting below error in appengine:-

PANIC RECOVER Post https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send: not an App Engine context goroutine

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please show the code that was not working with `request.Context`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply... I have updated my code. Please check my email function and let me know how we can use request.Context() instead of appengine.NewContext(c.Request())

Comment: The code you posted still uses `ctx := appengine.NewContext(c.Request())`. In your question you stated "when I am trying request.Context() getting request is not defined". Can you show *that* code?

Answer (score 2):

The [migration document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences) states that App Engine specific uflfetch package is superseded by the net/http package.

Replace this code:

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(c.Request())
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

with:

```
resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

Comment: The existing urlfetch package should still work in 1.11.  It's one for the migration from 1.11 to 1.12 that one has to migrate to the net/http package